# Is anything existing to translate some words based on a selected category in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, translation

In a given Ruby On Rails application an admin can create categories where he should be able to translate some few words and those words should be used when a user creates something and have selected a category.

For example, an admin has created the `garage` category and he translated the `product` word to `car`.
Then a user creates an entry with the `garage` category. Going to the pages where the `product` key is, it should be displayed `car` instead.

And this is also to be coupled with the website translation (en, fr, and so on).

So is there anything existing which could do this ?